# send SMS from WAP page

Tags: iphone, xhtml, sms, wap, wtai

This question is related to sending an SMS from a link in a WAP page?

Historically I have used sms: which has worked on SonyEricsson, Nokia and other such 'legacy' devices. An example of the mark-up would be;

```
<a href="sms:0123456789?body=test%20message">send</a>
```

I am aware that i-phone does not allow you to specify the body. If the body tag is present then the device closes the browser and opens the SMS application but does not go as far as taking the user to message creation. As such the following does not really work;

```
<a href="sms:0123456789?body=test%20message">send</a>
```

however, this partially does... in that it takes the user to the editor and selects the recipient.

```
<a href="sms:0123456789">send</a>
```

My tests with Android (HTC desire) cause the message editor to crash (with the above examples). I have managed to get the message editor to open successfully but not managed to pass any details (recipient or message body) using;

```
<a href="sms://0123456789">send</a>
```

Note the :// which is not correct according to the Nokia specs. Has anyone had any more success?

Sorry if this is a bit hazy, its probably more of a discussion than a question.

Comment: Did you ever have any luck with this?

Comment: I can't get this to work either: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787905/sms-url-on-android/5692400#5692400

Comment: possible duplicate of [Long Concatenated WAP PUSH over SMS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286054/long-concatenated-wap-push-over-sms)