# Long Concatenated WAP PUSH over SMS

Tags: sms, push, concatenation, wap

Can anyone kindly explain how to send a concatenated WAP PUSH SMS? I can send an SI that spans just one message, but I haven't figured out how to send one that spans multiple messages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you send a WAP Push message with a SMS Bearer, you've got a SMS with a User Data Header. This User Data Header looks like `0605040B8423F0` and contains so to say source and destination port for the WAP Push App in your phone. 0B84 is the destination port number (2948), 23F0 is the  source port number (9200).

To send a WAP Push longer than 133 Bytes you have to add a Concatenation Header to the UDH, the UDH  will then look like

`0B00033F020105040B8423F0` for the first SMS and

`0B00033F020205040B8423F0` for the second SMS

Split the remaining Wap-Push data in 128 Byte Chunks and append them to the UDH.

The glory details are part of the 3GPP Specification 23.040 found at http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/23040.htm

hth cheerio
  Steve

Comment: Nice answer, but I think I found a typo. The Wap-push data size will be 128 bytes not 129 because complete UDH data length (include first octet) is 12 bytes.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I have forgotten to take the UDH length into account.