# SMS URL on Android

Tags: android, sms

I was wanting to know if Android had a similar feature to the iPhone in that you can use an HTML A tag to send an SMS by setting the `HREF` attribute to the phone number you want to send the message to and prefixing it with "SMS:", i.e. `href="SMS:02313213"`

I've had a look around and can't seem to find anything that suggests it is available on Android.

Comment: do you know why smsto: does not work without phone number?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I found the following which may help you:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5724

You can check sub-section 2.5 or 2.6 of this RFC to give you some additional pointers on formulating a proper SMS URL.

Eg. using formal URI-spec as detailed in sub-section 2.2 of [rfc5724](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5724#section-2.2):

```
<a href="sms:+19725551212?body=hello%20there">SMS Me</a>
```

Notice the 'escaped' character for the 'space' in the example above.

Hopefully the Android browser will permit you to generate XHTML forms based on this syntax.  I believe they will (if I have some time over the next day, I shall give it a try on my Galaxy S).

Comment: Hyphens are allowed as well, for visual aid only.

Comment: I've been messing-around with this type of URL in actual SMS messages (meaning, sending `sms:number?body=foo` to an SMS recipient. Currently (Sept 2020), Android converts the phone number into a dial-number tap-able link while iOS converts the whole thing into a message-this-number-including-body tap-able link. So it seems that iOS is currently a little more SMS-URL-friendly than Android, at least outside of a web context.

Comment: Per the specification (rfc5724, sub-section 2.2) sms-recipients defined per RFC3966 - https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3966.

Answer (score 5):

href="sms:+xxx" works on my stock HTC Desire Android 2.2 browser and the Sense SMS app, but sms:+xxx?body= doesn't - error: invalid recipient(s). I was only really interested in setting the body - anyone seen / solved this problem?

My test page is here: http://jsbin.com/itama4/15

Comment: I am getting the same behavior, I think the issue is with how the sence app is working. On my phone (2.3.7 HTC EVO [Sense UI removed]), it works and opens up correctly in the Messaging app, but when doing it with a phone that has the Sense UI it gives an error and only works without body content.

Comment: I now have a Galaxy S2 with CyanogenMod 9 (default ICS SMS app) this does work for me - so I agree with you @Raymond.

Comment: Delayed response (my apologies) - the adoption of standards (like RFCs) are often in the 'eye of the implementer' so to speak.  Each implementing vendor chooses how they wish to interpret a spec or RFC.This is where interoperability testing sessions - e.g. IOP test-fests that Open Mobile Alliance (now OMA Specworks) have promoted for many years (https://omaspecworks.org/about/) and only recently surfaced by IETF based on QUIC (https://www.ietf.org/blog/quic-automated-interop-testing/) are so useful.

Answer (score 5):

If multiple recipients needed, this works:

Android:

```
sms:+15558675309,+15558675301?body=Text%20Here%20end!
```

iOS, macOS:

```
sms://open?addresses=+15558675309,+15558675301/&body=Text%20Here%20end!
```

Comment: I got idea from your answer.

Answer (score 4):

That should work:

```
<a href="sms:+437722735932">contact</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have noticed if you use a qrc code with text for `mms:<phone_number>?body=<your message here.>` this seem to work and avoid the error: invalid recipient(s)

here is a test qrc http://qrcode.kaywa.com/img.php?s=8&d=mms%3A555-555-5555%3Fbody%3DYour%20Message

Comment: "no useable data found"....... - perhaps this worked years ago, but it doesn't work now!

Answer (score 2):

If you wants to allow in Android and IOS, Following trick worked for me in both devices.

Without adding number :

```
sms:?&body<Your message goes here>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need a URL working for both Android and iOS you can do this trick:

```
sms:+123456789?&body=hello%20there
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a CSS trick to display one or the other:
[CSS media query to target only iOS devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30102792/css-media-query-to-target-only-ios-devices)

```
@supports (-webkit-touch-callout:none) {
  /* CSS specific to iOS devices */ 
  .android { display:none }
  }

@supports not (-webkit-touch-callout:none) {
  /* CSS for other than iOS devices */
  .ios { display:none }
  }

<a class="ios" href="sms://+12345">SMS me</a>
<a class="android" href="sms:+12345">SMS me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

For US toll free numbers I found that removing the country code (+1) made texts work. I don't have an iPhone, but I'm on a Mac and the OSX messages app had no trouble with the number sans country code:

`<a href="sms:8005555555">contact</a>`