# Android sms link with a body parameter

Tags: android, html, sms

I have a sms link on a webpage:

```
<a href="sms:+15553332222?body=message">SMS Link</a>
```

And that works great on my Nexus (running stock gingerbread) but two other phones (both HTC's on gingerbread with Sense UI) won't open the link saying "Invalid recipient". If I remove the body parameter on the link it works fine, but I need the body parameter. I've tried diffrent formatting of the number including `+15553332222`, `15553332222`, `5553332222`, `+1-555-333-2222`, and `555-333-2222`. I've also tried using `sms:`, `smsto:`, and `mms:` with the same result.

I'm I doing it wrong? Is this a known problem for HTC's phones? If it is, is there a work around?

Comment: some code, some logcat error would be appreciated.

Comment: can you paste your sms related code

Comment: What code are you looking for its just the html link.

Comment: Does the problem actually occur with the exact link in your question, i.e. a single-word body without any spaces/other special characters? If it only happens for longer bodies (e.g. sentences), you might not be URL-encoding the value of the `body` parameter  correctly.

Comment: I checked it using my HTC Desire HD, using Android 2.3.5 and it indeed failed there as you described (using ASCII only, no spaces). On my HTC One X using Android 4.0.3 it works correctly, so HTC just might have fixed it somewhere in between in their messaging app. (The behaviour was also mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5692400/151682 but without workaround)

Comment: Yes link as witten failed with no spaces or special characters. It does work on my Nexus running 2.3.7 so my guess is its a problem with older Sense versions or older versions of Android. Does anyone know of a work around?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<a href="sms://+35555&body=Helloworld">
```

Use the ://

Comment: It fixes a link for nexus 6p, but break link for other my android device. Do you know what devices require `//`?

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem, and got just a little bit closer.

Using

`<a href="sms:+351234567;body=hello%20world">One number with body text sep ;</a>`

sets the msisdn correctly but fails with error "Invalid recipient: `<body=hello world>`"

Android 4.0.3

HTC Sence 3.6

Comment: I'm not sure thats to much closer, it obviously getting some data but just not the correct data.