# React Native Linking SMS

Tags: javascript, react-native

Now that RN supports Linking cross-platform, I am wondering how to send an SMS with a preset message. Per the docs (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html#content):

> Try to open the given url with any of the installed apps.
>   You can use other URLs, like a location (e.g. "geo:37.484847,-122.148386"), a contact, or any other URL that can be opened with the installed apps.

My question is, what URI scheme do I follow to open an SMS with a predefined message? Is it cross-platform?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SMS URL on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787905/sms-url-on-android)

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, since the question wants a cross-platform solution and in fact iOS is slightly different.

Comment: If you want the user to select from contacts, refer my [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43781338/react-native-ios-open-message-app-with-default-text/53615008#53615008)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Have you considered and tried `sms:number?body=yourMessage`?

You can read up on it in [RFC 5724](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5724).

Comment: The separator seems to be `&` on iOS. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47834556/2083679

Answer (score 16):

there's a difference between the platforms with the "body" divider
you can use the following code to make it work:

```
function openUrl(url: string): Promise<any> {
  return Linking.openURL(url);
}
export function openSmsUrl(phone: string, body: string): Promise<any> {
  return openUrl(`sms:${phone}${getSMSDivider()}body=${body}`);
}
function getSMSDivider(): string {
  return Platform.OS === "ios" ? "&" : "?";
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I created a hook to send SMS messages:

```
import { useCallback } from 'react'
import { Linking, Platform } from 'react-native'

export default () => {
  const onSendSMSMessage = useCallback(async (phoneNumber, message) => {
    const separator = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? '&' : '?'
    const url = `sms:${phoneNumber}${separator}body=${message}`
    await Linking.openURL(url)
  }, [])

  return onSendSMSMessage
}
```

Comment: How can I use this hook?

Comment: 1 - Create a file for the hook. It could be called "useSendSMS"
2 - Import in the component that you want to use.
3 - Execute the hook. It will return an async function that receives a phone number and a message. Since it's an async function make sure to wrap the execution within a try catch block

Comment: This link may help you: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html

Comment: if I pass phonenumber with the country code then on iPad send button is not active, but if I pass phone-number without country code then send button is active on iPad

Answer (score 4):

OR you can simply do

```
url = `sms:${context.provider.state.driverPhoneNo}${Platform.OS === "ios" ? "&" : "?"}body=${""}`

Linking.openURL(url);
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work on both Platforms

```
 const operator = Platform.select({ios: '&', android: '?'});
 Linking.openURL(`sms:${operator}body=${options.title}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure this is not React Native-specific, and is just about linking on Android. Take a look at: [SMS URL on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787905/sms-url-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the react-packages react-native-communications(https://github.com/anarchicknight/react-native-communications). You can probably integrate the entire package or take parts of it