# React native iOS open message app with default text

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[image]

```
Code:
Linking.openURL('sms:'+number+'?body=Hi');
```

I try to open message app with mobile no and content.but mobile no and content combine together in to section.How to fix this issue?any help will be appricated.thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked into: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36163903/react-native-linking-sms?

Answer (score 9):

The working syntax on iOS (as at 11.2) appears to be `sms:123&body=mybody`, note the `&` as a separator rather than `?`.

Be warned though this `&` separator is contrary to [RFC5724](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5724#section-2.2) (and Android), so somewhat likely to change in future iOS versions.

Also, interestingly [Apple has this to say](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/SMSLinks/SMSLinks.html) (emphasis added):

> The format for URLs of this type is `sms:<phone>`, where `<phone>` is an
> optional parameter that specifies the target phone number of the SMS
> message. This parameter can contain the digits 0 through 9 and the
> plus (+), hyphen (-), and period (.) characters. **The URL string must
> not include any message text or other information.**

Comment: possible to pop back into the previous app .?

Answer (score 8):

If you want the user to select from contacts, you can pass `null` as follows:

```
Linking.openURL(`sms:&addresses=null&body=My sms text`);
```

Otherwise, in order to have multiple numbers already selected in iOS:

```
Linking.openURL(`sms:&addresses=replace_with_comma_seperated_numbers&body=My sms text`);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is working for me on ios.
you can provide comma separated numbers.

`` Linking.openURL(`sms:/open?addresses=923335251661,9231213341&body=My sms text`); ``

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i do....

```
Linking.openURL(`sms:${phone}?body=${msg}`)
```

give it a try!!!

Answer (score -1):

```
 For opening message box 

Linking.openURL(`sms:${"9210457731"}?body= `)


For opening message box  with text
Linking.openURL(`sms:${"9210457731"}?body= 'Hi ram ji' `)

 const onPressMobileNumberClick = (number) => {
    let phoneNumber = '';
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      phoneNumber = `tel:${number}`;
    } else {
      phoneNumber = `telprompt:${number}`;
    }

    Linking.openURL(phoneNumber);
 }

 const onPressEmailClick = (email) => {
    Linking.openURL('mailto:'+email)
  //  Linking.openURL('mailto:Care@amazon.com')
 }
     
 const onPressMessageClick = (email) => {
    Linking.openURL(`sms:${"9210457731"}?body= `)
 }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 