# Javascript text a message rathen than email

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, ios

I'm looking for a way to use JavaScript to open texts on ios or android when a link is clicked. Currently, you can use the `mailto` links in HTML to mail a link and open the link in an empty email. I'm wondering how I can do the same using text. For example, a user clicks and button and it will open the messages app and auto-fill with some information similar to the `mailto` only for messages. How can this be done?

Current code:

```
<button onclick="text()">text message</button>
<script>
 function text() {
  //Code for text messages
 }
</script>
```

Comment: You can try this: [SMS URL on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787905/sms-url-on-android)

Comment: The issue with this is it only works in android, I’m looking for a iOS and Android solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sms:`  works for both ios and android.

For ios:

> The sms scheme is used to launch the Messages app. The format for URLs of this type is “sms:”, where  is an optional parameter that specifies the target phone number of the SMS message. This parameter can contain the digits 0 through 9 and the plus (+), hyphen (-), and period (.) characters. The URL string must not include any message text or other information.
>
> The following examples show strings formatted for Safari and for
> native apps.
>
> HTML links:

```
<a href="SMS:"> Launch Messages App</a> <a href="sms:1-408-555-1212">New SMS Message</a>
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/SMSLinks/SMSLinks.html

Comment: Not sure if it's because I'm not an older device but the link didn't go anywhere when I tried to access it on my phone. Does it work on older ios or android devices?